# navigation from one jsp to another jsp using db result column as a hyper link

Tags: jsp

i am fetching DB result using a class  DAO and displaying the result on web page(.jsp file) using beans now i have to navigate the user to another jsp page while i have to useone of the column as hyper link to navigate the user. how to do it?

Comment: have u tried something ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement properly then probably you need to dynamically create your URL to which the user will be redirected and use that URL for hyper linking that particular column at the time of rendering your entire resultSet on your jsp page. You may find difficulties for dynamically generating your redirection URL based on some ID parameters of your resultSet.

For this you can use something similar to the below code snippet:

```
String uid = <some value from your resultSet for that particular record>    

String schemeProtocol = request.getScheme();
String serverName = request.getServerName();
int portNumber = request.getServerPort();
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();

String redirectionURL = schemeProtocol + "://" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + contextPath + "/app/UserInfo?uid=" + uid;
```

and use this redirectionURL on your anchor attribute.

Comment: Did you get my explanation?